# How to fill 4d array/matrix in python correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I’m quite new with python, so I would really appreciate your comments and explanations.
I have a dataframe with 40000 entries:

```
id              40000 non-null int64
feature_1        40000 non-null float64
feature_2        40000 non-null float64
feature_3        40000 non-null float64
feature_4        40000 non-null float64
```

And I need to calculate for each of the id numbers following equation using coefficient c_n for each feature:

```
eq_n=feature_1*c_1+feature_2*c_2+feature_3*c_3+feature_4*c_4
```

`c_n` can be from 0 to 1 with the step of `0.1`(0,0.1,0.2,...1)
So the number of combinations will be `11^4`: 11 because of the step (0,0.1,...1) and 4 because of the 4 features.

I believe that I need to create `4d` array with coefficients first and then by using loops make further calculations. 
But I stuck with the process of creating and filling the `4d` matrix with those coefficients. 
I tried to create a matrix using `np.zeros([11,4,11,4])` but I’m not quite sure that I properly chose the dimensions indexes according to the requirements of `11^4` and I'm not quite see how I can fill this array with the required elements.

I started with a simpler configuration 
by creating an array of zeros and changing it in a loop but it’s surely needs adjustments, because it covers much lower quantity of combinations. Please see what I did below:

```
M=df # dataframe without Id column for simplicity 
# calc is the name of the function that makes further calculations using 
#the product of arrays 
K=[0,0,0,0] # coefficient array
J=[0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1] # steps for coefficients
ind=0 # for assigning a new element to a coefficient array
for i in K:
        for z in j:
            K[ind]=z
            calc(prod=K*M)
            print(prod)
  ind=ind+1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
transf = np.array(list(itertools.product(*(np.linspace(0,1,11),)*4))).reshape(11,11,11,11,4)
output = np.einsum('ijklm,nm->ijkn', transf, df.values)
```

Unfortunately, this might give you MemoryErrors (it does for me) as the final output is pretty big.  11**4 * 40000 * 64bit = 4.5GB

Comment: Oh, thank you, never used itertools module before but I think I found easier way for solving my task, please see in answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to leave the idea of using of 4d array and I came up with an easier algorithm:

- Figure out the number of combinations and create a 2d array with those combinations.

  As I mentioned earlier the number of combinations is 11**4
- So, the next thing is to get each of those combinations by using following function:

  `def combinations(n, m):
          steps = np.arange(0,1.1,0.1)
          qty_of_combs = n**m
          combs = np.zeros((qty_of_combs, m), dtype=float) 
          for i in range(m): #for each column
              k = n**i
              q = 0
              while (q < qty_of_combs):
                  for z in range(n):
                      for j in range(k):
                          combs[q, i] = steps[z]
                          q += 1
          return combs`
- The final step is to calculate output by using each of the combination.

  `comb_ar=combinations(11,4)
   for i in range(comb_ar.shape[0]):
           output=comb_ar[i,:]*df`

df here is only with features columns so we can calculate a product of arrays.